# Loop through JSON Array and display results in table - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

This question probably has been asked many times, but i cant get a solution.

I'm calling to a API like this:

```
public function getLeaderBoardArray($leaderBoardStats) {
        $array = [];
        $ex = $leaderBoardStats;

        dd($ex);

        return $array;
    }
```

This is the result I get when I (DD) (Die-Dump it):

```
{#201 ▼
  +"Start": 0
  +"Count": 100
  +"ResultCount": 100
  +"Results": array:100 [▼
    0 => {#199 ▼
      +"Player": {#186 ▼
        +"Gamertag": "Ferro2Clutch"
        +"Xuid": null
      }
      +"Rank": 1
      +"Score": {#195 ▶}
    }
    1 => {#188 ▶}
    2 => {#200 ▶}
    3 => {#203 ▶}
    4 => {#206 ▶}
    5 => {#209 ▶}
    6 => {#212 ▶}
....... and so on till 100
```

How can a loop through this array and display Players Gamertag.

This i what I'm doing right now:

```
 public function getLeaderBoardArray($leaderBoardStats) {
        $array = [];
        $array['Gamertag_1'] = $leaderBoardStats->Results[0]->Player->Gamertag;
        $array['Csr_1'] = $leaderBoardStats->Results[0]->Score->Csr;

        $array['Gamertag_2'] = $leaderBoardStats->Results[1]->Player->Gamertag;
        $array['Csr_2'] = $leaderBoardStats->Results[1]->Score->Csr;

        // and so on til 10....

        return $array;
    }
```

As you can see, this would be a pain to do till 100 for each leader-board.

Is there an easier method like somehow doing a for each loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked a very similar question yesterday and I'm going to give you a very similar answer today.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections

Use the `map()` Collection functionality to convert each item to a more digestable array.

```
$results = collect($leaderBoardStats->Results);
$gamers  = $results->map(function($item, $key)
{
    return [
        'gamertag' => $item->Player->Gamertag,
        'csr'      => $item->Score->Csr,
    ]
});
```

This will give you an array that looks like ...

```
[
    ['gamertag' => "name", 'csr' => 11111],
    ['gamertag' => "name", 'csr' => 11111],
    ['gamertag' => "name", 'csr' => 11111],
    ['gamertag' => "name", 'csr' => 11111],
];
```

Then, in your view, you can do this to build a table.

```
@foreach ($gamers->all() as $gamer)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $gamer['gamertag'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $gamer['csr'] }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

All it takes. Laravel Collections are probably one of the strongest aspects of the entire framework and are incredibly robust and well built. If you have an array-related question, chances are that documentation has a collection-related answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a simple loop to iterate through your results. for example, I like using a foreach loop

```
$array = [];

foreach ($leaderBoardStats->Results as $stat) {
    array[] = [
        'gamer_tag' => $stat->Player->Gamertag,
        'csr'       => $stat->Score->Csr
    ];
}

return $array;
```

A better more advanced approach would be to map this so you don't have to create any extra arrays.

```
   return array_map(function ($stat) {
       return [
           'gamer_tag' => $stat->Player->Gamertag, 
           'csr' => $stat->Score->Csr
       ];
   }, $leaderBoardStats->Results);
```